# SwiftMailer Error

Tags: php, api, swiftmailer

So I am trying to setup swift mailer to work with the Mandrill API, but it keeps throwing the following error:

Failures:Array ( [0] => example@email.com ) (I have a proper email in this place in my code)

My code is as follows:

```
        $subject = 'Hello from Mandrill, PHP!';
    // approved domains only!
    $from = array('example2@email.com' =>'Your Name');
    $to = array(
     'example@email.com'  => 'Recipient1 Name'
    );

    $text = "Mandrill speaks plaintext";
    $html = "Mandrill speaks HTML";

    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587);
    $transport->setUsername(getenv('my@mandrillemail.com'));
    $transport->setPassword(getenv('mymandrillpass'));
    $swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $message = new Swift_Message($subject);
    $message->setFrom($from);
    $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
    $message->setTo($to);
    $message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

    // Pass a variable name to the send() method
    if (!$swift->send($message, $failures))
    {
      echo "Failures:";
      print_r($failures);
    }
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Are your username and password really set as environment variables? `$transport->setUsername(getenv('my@mandrillemail.com'));`

Comment: Riiighhhttt... Lol! I replaced (getenv('my@mandrillemail.com')) with ('my@mandrillemail.com'). I am now getting the following error:
Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "my@mandrillemail.com" using 2 possible authenticators' Any idea what that means?

Comment: that means your username and password you provided to the SMTP server are incorrect.  Do they require that SSL be used and can you confirm the username and password you are supplying are correct?  So I see your responses, you can put "@drew010" at the beginning of your comment and I'll get a notification.

Comment: @drew010 Okay interesting. I'm not sure if they require SSL. How should I find this out?

Comment: Their [FAQ](http://help.mandrill.com/forums/20689696-smtp-integration) isn't completely clear.  It says port 25 or 587 use `STARTTLS` encryption and port 465 uses SSL but they don't say if `STARTTLS` is required or not.  But for the most part it seems like the authentication is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SSL and port 465.

```
$xport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 465, 'ssl');
$xport->setUsername('mandrilluser')
      ->setPassword('mandrillpass');
```

See if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

My problem ended up being that I had to change from using the actual Mandrill account password to the API in the ->setPassword() variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is purely an error with your credentials, cross check if the password you are using is actually the token generated by Mandrill or not .

Password doesn't mean the 'password' of your account !!